# Measurement Protocol - Enhanced E-commerce Tracking currency issue

Tags: google-analytics, get, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am having issues with Measurement Protocol. According to docs I should send "cu" - CurrencyCode to set a currency. I am not getting that currency in my analitics view. It is showed in USD.

My sample hit

```
v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-105189848-1&cid=555&ds=&z=&dh=lechtest.roboticket.com&dp=%2FTransaction2&dt=Transaction&pr1id=3923915&pr1nm=Lech%20Pozna%C5%84%20-%20Wis%C5%82a%20Krak%C3%B3w&pr1ca=ticket&pr1br=&pr1va=Darmowy&pr1ps=&pr1pr=0&pr2id=3923914&pr2nm=Lech%20Pozna%C5%84%20-%20Wis%C5%82a%20Krak%C3%B3w&pr2ca=ticket&pr2br=&pr2va=Darmowy&pr2ps=&pr2pr=0&pr3id=3923913&pr3nm=Lech%20Pozna%C5%84%20-%20Wis%C5%82a%20Krak%C3%B3w&pr3ca=ticket&pr3br=&pr3va=Darmowy&pr3ps=&pr3pr=0&ti=4724692&ta=roboticket&tr=0&tt=&ts=0&tcc=&pa=purchase&cu=PLN
```

I tested that with [google hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) and it looked okay, parameter was even linked to docs.

[Docs refference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cu)

Any clue what I am doing wrong? I'd appreciate any help with that currency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Yes, you misunderstand what that parameter does. Your views shows values in the currency that is selected in the view settings. If you send a currency designator that's different from the selected currency (and it is one of the supported currencies) then GA will convert your amounts from that currency to the currency set in the view. That's a feature to support shops that support multiple currencies.